# CVE alert for MySQL

Tags: mysql, security

do you know if is there a tool ( possibly free ) that alert me if are present new versions or security patch for my MySQL instances?

We have more than 200 MySQL instances and I need a tool, like a control panel, that alert me. This kind of information is not provided by the MySQL Enterprise Monitor...

Thanks

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific tool for testing mysql instances, you can still use Openvas, Nessus or other vulnerability scanners which will help you in determining if your instance is vulnerable or need patches.